# one file fails to execute pyinstaller

Tags: executable, pyinstaller

I have been using pyisnataller to create executable applications of my python 3.6.5 scripts. The scripts are GUI interfaces. I have used a recipe from a previous stackoverflow post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile/44352931#44352931)

It has been effective but am running into a slight snafu trying one file a simple GUI.

Why does the executable fail to run? The temporary folder created has the two files added within about.spec?

Any help would be appreciated!

I would have placed the code, and the spec file here but stackoverflow didnt seem to perform the formatting well enough to send the message. I tried backticks four spaces, a missing line followed by eight space, and

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is an ill posed question. So, turns out the pyinstaller creates a warn_yourscript_.txt file and the post warnings in the creation of the executable. The file is located in the working directory/build/*yourscript*/warn_yourscript_.txt. Having looked into the file, there was a warning about not being able to load or missing the TKinter module. The myscript.py was running smoothly under python 3.6.5, but I may have started my script from a starter on the internet and may have been from an earlier python. I have several pythons loaded on my machine, python could find it but pyinstaller could not? I changed out myscript to reflect earlier success with tkinter instead.